# Tell me the difference between both. Its is c++ code of insertion in tree

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

Check the two functions and tell me the difference between them. Thanks if you tell me the difference of both pointers

```
void binaryTree::insert1(binaryNode *root,string value)
{
    if(root==NULL)
        root = CreateNode(value);
    else if( value > root->data )
        insert1 (root->right,value);
    else if( value < root->data )
        insert1 (root->left,value);
}
```

and

```
void binaryTree::insert2(string value)
{
    insert2(root,value);
}

void binaryTree::insert2(binaryNode *&root,string value)
{    
    if(root==NULL)
        root = CreateNode(value);
    else if( value > root->data )
        insert2 (root->right,value);
    else if( value < root->data )
        insert2 (root->left,value);
}
```

Comment: In future questions, it would help if you told us what you want, what your problems are, what you think about those problems, and how you have tried to solve them.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that in the first version you pass the pointer *by value*, meaning it gets copied and in the function you only modify the copy.

In the second version you pass the pointer *by reference*, which means changes to it will be reflected outside of the function.

Comment: But first one doesn't work. When I use insert1, nothing gets inserted. But when I use insert2, it works. Why?

Comment: @MADCODER: Regarding "Why?", that's what this answer, answers. Study the answer. Think about it.

Comment: @MADCODER When you assign to `root` in the first version of the function, you are only assigning to a *copy*, changing a copy will of course not change the original. In the second version of the function, `root` is a *reference* of the original, assigning to `root` in that version assigns to the original reference. References is a basic and important key concept in C++, one that you need to learn and understand together with pointers, classes and `for` loops and all other basic but key concepts in C++.